# request tracker fails with mysql configuration error

Tags: mysql, database, perl

I am trying to install request tracker.

the make testdeps says all the dependencies are present.

how ever the problem is rt is unable to connect to mysql.

```
[root@128 rt-4.0.6]# make initialize-database
/usr/bin/perl -I/opt/rt4/local/lib -I/opt/rt4/lib sbin/rt-setup-database --action init --prompt-for-dba-password
In order to create or update your RT database, this script needs to connect to your  mysql instance on localhost as root
Password:
Working with:
Type:       mysql
Host:       localhost
Name:       rt4
User:       rt_user
DBA:        root
Failed to connect to dbi:mysql:;host=localhost as user 'root': Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)make: *** [initialize-database] Error 255

[root@128 rt-4.0.6]# mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I am starting to think mysql is not correctly configured. The following commands wont work.

```
Service mysqld status 
/etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

there is no file /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock.

Please let me know whet the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think mysql server was not in place.

although i had installed mysql using

```
yum install mysql
```

any one have comments on what i installed by above command?